# Change scenario in form Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to change scenario in view page by jQuery.
There is a checkbox in my form, I want inputbox be required in checked checkbox.

my rule:

```
public function rules() {
        return [
               .
               .
               .
               ['pass' , 'required', 'on'=> 'checked']
        ]
}
```

my view page:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'check')->checkbox()?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'Pass')->textInput(['maxlength' => 20])?>
```

Comment: I have delete the answer because is not related to jquery .validatio but to the use of yii2 scenario ... . If you want validation client side probably is better an ajax validation o a local jquery validation without scenario ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set up your rule like this:

```
public function rules() {
    $checkBoxID = Html::getInputId($this, 'check');

    return [
        /* other rules */
        ['pass' , 'required', 
            'when' => function($model) {
                return $model->check;
            },
            'whenClient'=> "function(attribute, value){
                return $('#{$checkBoxID}').prop('checked');
            }",
            'on' => 'checked'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Read about [conditional validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) and [whenClient validator property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail). Also consider naming you scenario more informative, e.g. by its purpose, like `'on' => 'sign-up'`, or `'on' => 'login'`. Scenario is useful when you need certain rules to apply in particular cases, but you need to specify this scenario explicitly. Either when you instantiate a model

```
$model = new MyModel();
$model->scenario = 'sign-up';
```

and passing it into a view, or before doing any validation after `$model->load($data)`